# Get an instance of class from one assembly at another assembly but at the same project

Tags: c#, .net

I writing a project that holds few class libraries.
In the lower layer i have a class that look like this:

```
namespace firstclasslibrary
{

    public abstract class Base<T> where T :SomeClass
    {
            public static Base<T> Current 
            { 
                 get 
                 {
                       return new Base() ;
                 }
            }
    }
}
```

and then in a different class library i have:

```
namespace secondclasslibrary
{
      public class Derived : Base
      {
           ///some kind of singleton ....
      }
}
```

now at the first class library i have another class that use the abstract class like this:

```
namespace firstclasslibrary
{
      public class JustAClass
      {
            public Base<SomeClass> baseclass = baseclass.Current;


            ////do some other things.....
      }
}
```

if all the classes were under the same class library i was able to get the instance of the Derived  , but since it is a different library i get null it doesn't get the instance i was created in the main project.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Is there something missing in the code? There is a `Base<T>` class, but not the `Base` class that you inherit, or the `base` class that you are creating an instance of from the `Base<T>.Current` property. The `base` in the property can't be the class itself, as you can't create instances of an abstract class.

Comment: changed the new base() to new Base(), but i didn't wrote here the full code.the idea is that the base class return the instance of the Derived  if there is an instance if there isn't it will create one.(i hope it clear now).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you are suggesting as long as the second class library has a reference to the first.

Comment: the second library has a reference to the first one but the first library has nothing with the second.

Comment: The first library would need a reference to the second library to be able to create an instance of a class in it.

Comment: The idea is to have a layers in the code so since the first library is the lowest layer i don't want to include the the second library int the first one but i have no problem to include the first in the second, that the reason i try to make it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If the first library doesn't have a reference to the second library, then it doesn't know about the concrete implementation of the class, so it can't create an instance of it on its own.

You would have to tell the class how to create an instance, for example:

```
namespace firstclasslibrary {

  public abstract class Base {

    private static Base _current = null;

    public static Func<Base> CreateInstance;

    public static Base Current { 
      get {
        if (_current == null) {
          _current = CreateInstance();
        }
        return _current;
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Before using the `Current` property, you have to set the `CreateInstance` property, to "learn" the class how to create the instance:

```
Base.CreateInstance = () => new Derived();
```

You could also expand on this by making the `_current` property protected, so that the constructor of the `Derived` class can set itself as the current instance if you create an instance of the class instead of using the `Current` property.

Comment: In the Base class i have an inner class that create an instance :              private class SingletonCreator
{
      internal static readonly Application<T> _instance = instance;
            static SingletonCreator() { }
}

Comment: @roybarak: Then, what is the question?

Comment: Like i said, it work fine as long as i have it all under the same class library but the moment i take the base class out to different library (the first layer) and i create the instance at the upper layer and want to use it it again at the first layer it doesn't work.so my question is if i can do what i plan to do ,is it possible to use an instance from upper layer in the bottom layer? (and thanks for the help).

Comment: @roybarak: Yes, that is possible, by injecting what's needed to create the instance. That means that you can't use it to create an instance in a static member, you have to make the singleton creation lazy, so that you can do the injection before you use the singleton.

Comment: thanks for the information but i didnt' understand what you mean in your last answer "... you have to make the singleton creation lazy..."

Comment: @roybarak: A lazy creation of a singleton creates the instance when it's first needed, not in the static constructor.